# Godot: How to get a variable from a non instanced scene

Tags: variables, godot

Godot: How to get a variable from a non instanced scene

I don't want to instance the scene.

Answer (score 0):

i am answering my own question because i figured it out.

you can use singletons:
http://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/step_by_step/singletons_autoload.html

Comment: Link only answers are not considered good practice. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer